# Php session starts and end according to links?

Tags: php, mysql

I have links like Date, Day and Time on a page. If somebody clicks on 'Date', I want a session to start. And then the same way clicking on 'Day' the previous session stops and a new one is created. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, just use session_start() and session_destroy()

Comment: It sounds like you shouldn't be using sessions for whatever you are using them for (at least not in the way you are using them at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure *why* you want to use sessions for this, but yes - it is possible with AJAX.

You define two links, let's call them start and stop for example:

```
<a id="start">Start</a>
<a id="stop">Stop</a>
```

You then use Javascript (this example will use the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/)) to make a request to a back end handler, which will call `session_start()` or `session_stop()` appropriately. You can (optionally) serialize the user's session when they stop it, if some work must be done on it later.

First, an example of the AJAX request. In the page, you want to establish events to call a common function to make an asynchronous request to start or end a user's session. We do that by creating an anonymous function that will run once the DOM is ready:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // Make the request to start or stop a session
    function asyncSessionMolester(uri, val) {
    $.ajax({
        url: uri
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            'action':session,
            'value':val
        },
        success: function(remoteResponse, textStatus) {
           alert('Session now in mode ' + toggle);
           // do other stuff you want to do on success
        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
            // There is a lot more data in xhr, this just shows what the server
            // wrote to the browser in the console for debugging.
            // Handle failure here
            console.log(xhr.textResponse);
        }
    });

    // now, our events:

    $('#start').click(function() { 
        asyncSessionMolestor('/ajax.php', 'start');
    }); 

    $('#stop').click(function() {
        asyncSessionMolestor('/ajax.php', 'stop');
    });
});
</script>
```

Now, you need to create some PHP that lives at `/ajax.php` and does the following things:

- Make sure the user has the rights to request it if a session is established
- Check for the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header, if it's not there someone is accessing it directly via browser (bail out if so)
- Check your POST data for `action` and `value`. If action is `session` then `switch()` on the value. If `start`, then start the session. If `stop` then stop the session.
- Send JSON response back which you can examine in the ajax call

If you need to save the session for later analysis or work call `serialize($_SESSION)`, or even `json_encode($_SESSION)` prior to destroying it.

Caveats:

- You *must* handle success properly. The user needs to know they have no session anymore. Perhaps a redirect on success. You should also handle failure properly. I gave only a crude example.
- You *must not* print anything in the code that starts the session prior to starting it.
- You probably don't want to use sessions like you are, but you asked if it was possible, and it is.
- Code was not tested, just given as an example.
- No security was shown in this example. At the least you want some kind of CSRF protection in place, and of course sanitize your input.

**Edit**

If you want the same link to start / stop depending on the state, you can just set a variable to keep track of it, e.g.:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var state = false;

    ... ajax stuff as above

    $('#date').click(function() { 
       switch(state) {
           case true:
              // We successfully created or recreated a session
              asyncSessionMolester('/ajax.php', 'stop');
              break;
           case false:
              // User has not yet created a session
              asyncSessionMolester('/ajax.php', 'start');
              break;
       }
    });
});
</script>
```

And you would have only one link, with the ID of `date`. Just be sure that the AJAX function is the function that updates the `state` variable, depending on the success of the call. Just remember, it's asynchronous - you probably want to prevent the user from going click happy.

That should get you going in the direction you want to go, or possibly illustrate why it might not be a good idea. But, that's one way to accomplish it.